# Calculating conditional expectation and mean time to failure

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I was reading text on probability where they state:

$$\operatorname{Ex}[C]=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i\cdot\Pr[C=i]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\Pr[C>i]$$

Now assuming there is a system which fails at each step with probability $p$. What is the expected time to failure? They calculated this using the above relation.

Assuming $C$ is the random variable which is equal to the number of steps until first failure occurs. Thus $\operatorname{Ex}[C]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\Pr[C>i]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^i=\frac{1}{p}$. I was able to understand till here.

Now they say that $\operatorname{Ex}[C|A]=1+\operatorname{Ex}[C]$ where $A$ is the event when system does not fail on the first step. They reasoned that conditioning on $A$ is equivalent to taking a first step without failure and then starting over without conditioning. I am not able to understand how this reasoning works. Can anyone help?

Further when I try to calculate $\operatorname{Ex}[C|A]$, $\operatorname{Ex}[C|A]=1.\Pr[C=1|A]+2.\Pr[C=2|A]+3.\Pr[C=3|A]\dots$.

Now $\Pr[C=1|A]=0$ as we know system doesn't fail on the first step. Thus $\operatorname{Ex}[C|A]=0+2.Pr[C=2|A]+3.\Pr[C=3|A]\dots$

Now $\Pr[C=i|A]$ for $i>1$ should be simply $\Pr[C=i]$ as if system doesn't fail on the first step, the probability of failing at step $i$ is still $p$. Thus $\operatorname{Ex}[C|A]=0+2.\Pr[C=2]+3.\Pr[C=3]\dots$ which is equal to $\operatorname{Ex}[C]-1.\Pr[C=1]=\operatorname{Ex}[C]-p$. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Pr[C=i|A]\neq\Pr[C=i]$ because $\Pr[C=2|A]=p$ while $\Pr[C=2]=(1-p)\cdot p$

What you have is $\Pr[C>i+1] = (1-p)\cdot\Pr[C>i]$ and $\Pr[C>1|A] = 1$

So by induction: $\Pr[C>i+1|A] = \Pr[C>i]$

From there :

$\operatorname{Ex}[C|A]=\Pr[C>0|A]+\Pr[C>1|A]+\Pr[C>2|A]\dots$
$\operatorname{Ex}[C|A]=1+\Pr[C>1|A]+\Pr[C>2|A]\dots$
$\operatorname{Ex}[C|A]=1+\Pr[C>0]+\Pr[C>1]\dots$

Therefore :
$\operatorname{Ex}[C|A]=1+\operatorname{Ex}[C]$

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. However why didn't you include $Pr[C>0|A]$, which should be $1$, in the calculation of $Ex[C|A]$?

Comment: And it would also be really helpful if you could explain me their reasoning that "conditioning on A is equivalent to taking a first step without failure and then starting over without conditioning". Thanks.

Comment: $\Pr[C=0] = 0$ so $\Pr[C>0] = \Pr[C>0|A] = 1$. I just forgot it twice, I'm editing the post. "conditioning on A is equivalent to taking a first step without failure and then starting over without conditioning" comes from what I've shown $\Pr[C>i+1|A] = \Pr[C>i]$

Comment: $$\operatorname{Ex}[C]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\Pr[C>i]=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\Pr[C>i]$$

Comment: I still can't understand "conditioning on A is equivalent to taking a first step without failure and then starting over without conditioning" intuitively, that how can we just add 1, as at first step system doesn't fail and then calculate the expected value without conditioning.

Comment: "$A$ is the event when system does not fail on the first step" so it is "taking a first step without failure", then instead of doing $\Pr[C>i+1|A]$ you "start over without conditioning" ie $\Pr[C>i]$. Basically, because you didn't fail the first step and because the probability $p$ of failing at each step is independent of the step number, you can "slide" your window back in time and pretend like you start again.